# Cross in Zapf Dingbats not rendering in iText 7 PDF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, unicode, itext7

I'm constructing a PDF file using iText 7, in an ASP.NET web application written in VB.

Using the following code to render a tick/check mark in a table cell works correctly:

```
Dim symbolFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.ZAPFDINGBATS, PdfEncodings.ZAPFDINGBATS)

New Cell().Add(New Paragraph().Add(New Text(Convert.ToChar(&H2713)))).SetFont(symbolFont)
```

However, when I replace the unicode with &H2715 nothing is rendered. 2715 should be a cross, as per this PDF: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2700.pdf

1) Why does a cross not render when I change the code to 2715?

2) How do I render a tick or cross using iText 7?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for a check mark:

```
Dim symbolFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.ZAPFDINGBATS, PdfEncodings.WINANSI)

New Cell().Add(New Paragraph().Add(New Text(Convert.ToChar(&H51)))).SetFont(symbolFont)
```

And this piece for cross:

```
New Cell().Add(New Paragraph().Add(New Text(Convert.ToChar(&H53)))).SetFont(symbolFont)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Do you know why my code rendered a tick but not a cross?

Comment: Swing and a miss. 51 seems to be star, and 53 seems to be asterisk.